# Anker Battery shuts off for HP Dv6 2064ca

Tags: laptop, battery, power

I bought high capacity (12 cells) from Anker. Battery provides 3 hrs backup time when browsing or sitting idle.  When laptop gets hot the cooling fan start to speedup. Especially while watching movies or running games. Battery cut off power and laptop shuts off. It seems battery cannot draw extra power. It only works on A/C adapter.  I cleaned the clogged air outlet and also have laptop cooler but doesn't help much.

Anybody have any idea what could be wrong with laptop/battery?

Answer (score 0):

Since it only runs on the A/C adapter, can I assume your current laptop battery is no good? Running on a 'bad' laptop battery will draw significantly higher current than a good one. This could be the cause of the battery shutting down as well as why it gets so hot. The fans kicking on could be a result of the heat generated by the bad battery, making it seem like the fans are what is shutting your UPS down.

Try removing the laptop battery and see if the helps.

Comment: thanks for answer.  I dont have UPS. I am referring to Laptop battery.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Have you tried contact the person you bought it from? It definitely sounds defective to me, there isn't a whole lot to a battery and it should just be a plug and play affair without headache.

Comment: i bought from Amazon (Anker High Capacity Laptop Battery (12-cell / 8800mAh) for HP Pavilion DV6 DV6T). Suppose to be good quality laptop battery. They replaced it with another battery but it is behaving the same